# Getting IIS7.5 details through Powershell

Tags: powershell

$iis=Get-WmiObject -namespace root/MicrosoftIISv2 -query "select * from iiswebservicesetting whe 
re name='W3SVC'"

OR

$iis = Get-WmiObject -namespace root/MicrosoftIISv2 -class  IIsWebServiceSetting

The above as worked very well for me in case of IIS6.0.
But in case of IIS7.5 the namespace is root\WebAdministration.
I am not sure what query i need to run to get the data that i used to obtain when i ran the WMI command for IIS6.0.You can also tell me the class that i need to use.

2) i need to get some information for IIS ASP.Net configuration.
The .NET Framework defines a set of
elements that implement configuration settings, and the ASP.NET configuration schemacontains elements that control how ASP.NET Web applications behave.

I need to get Details like SessionState,Authorisation,authentication mode,compilation etc

I need to know which NAMESPACE i should use and WHICH CLASS within this namespace i need to use.

Please anyone help me with above 2 problems as its very much needed for me to move ahead with my work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the PowerShell Module for Web Administration for IIS 7.5. On a 2008R2 box running IIS, run the following commands and see what you can find.

```
PS> Import-Module WebAdministration
PS> Get-Command -module WebAdministration
```

There is also an IIS provider. You can cd into IIS:\ and use get-item/set-item cmdlets.